# Creating a Custom Exception

Tags: java, exception, throws

I'm trying to create a method `f1(x)` that throws an exception when x equals 5. After that I will try to call that method from another method `f2()` to invoke that exception. Then I have to have `f2()` recover by calling `f1(x+1)`. I tried coding something, but I'm stuck. Here is the code:

```
public class FiveException extends Exception {

public void f1(int x) throws FiveException {
    if (x == 5) {
        throw new FiveException();
    }
}

public void f2() {
    int x = 5;
    try {
        f1(x);
    }catch (FiveException e) {
        System.out.println("x is 5");
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    FiveException x5 = new FiveException();
    x5.f2();
}

}
```

The print statement works, but I'm not sure how to call `f(x+1)`. Any help on how to fix this and any techniques to write exceptions is appreciated.

Comment: Your code that throws the exception should not be in the FiveException class.

Comment: Where do you want to call `f1(x + 1)`? Inside which method?

Comment: @fhelwanger I tried calling `f1(x + 1)` under the catch statement in `f2()` but it was giving me an error.

Answer (score 1):

Because `f1` throws `FiveException`, wherever you call `f1` you must either catch the exception or throw it to the method calling the method that raises the exception. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FiveException {
    FiveException x5 = new FiveException();
    x5.f1(1);
}
```

Or:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FiveException x5 = new FiveException();

    try {
        x5.f1(1);
    } catch (FiveException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But your code is confusing... normally, it isn't the exception class that throws itself, you have other classes that throw the exception class.

If it's being invoked inside a catch statement, you must surround it with another `try-catch`, 'cause the code inside `catch` isn't protected, like this:

```
public void f2() {
    int x = 5;
    try {
        f1(x);
    }catch (FiveException e) {
       System.out.println("x is 5");
       try {
           f1(x + 1);
       } catch (FiveException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

But this code is ugly, you can write the following:

```
public void f2() {
    int x = 5;
    fProtected(x);
    fProtected(x + 1);
}

private void fProtected(int x) {
    try {
        f1(x);
    }catch (FiveException e) {
       System.out.println("x is 5");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I will study this and will see if this is the desired code I'm looking for.